# asp.net TreeView reloads unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a TreeView and a XMLDataSource on my form.  When I click on a Node in the TreeView, the TreeView reloads back to the initial state and the SelectedNodeChange event is not called. My program works fine when running from localhost, but I run into the explained issue when the program is deployed.

I have done a simple test program that will add the node text of the selected node into a Label:

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Root>
  <node1>abc</node1>
</Root>
```

My aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs"      Inherits="SalesTools.test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div style="width: 285px">

        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ExpandDepth="1" Height="36px" Width="284px" DataSourceID="XmlDataSourceTemp" OnSelectedNodeChanged="TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged">
            <DataBindings>
                <asp:TreeNodeBinding DataMember="Folder" SelectAction="SelectExpand" TargetField="FolderID" TextField="FolderName" />
            </DataBindings>
        </asp:TreeView>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSourceTemp" runat="server" DataFile="~/XMLFile1.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>

    </div>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my .cs file

```
namespace SalesTools

{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
       }

        protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        }

    }
}
```